# I have issue with encoding pdf generator

Tags: encoding, fpdf, cyrillic

I try to wrote php code who can generate PDF file for valcher adding to database and create PDF file, Everything is fine but encoding is not. I try to many things but nothing. My current code is :
I use fpdf Library

```
<?php
include("connect_new.php");
require('fpdf.php');

$code = substr(str_shuffle('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'), 0, 10);

$amount = $_POST['amount'];
$expiryDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 year'));

$sql = "INSERT INTO vouchers (code, amount, expiry_date) VALUES ('$code', '$amount',     '$expiryDate')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "Ваучърът е създаден успешно!<br>";
$enc = 'UTF-8'; // Използвайте UTF-8 за кирилица

// Създаване на PDF файл
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->AddFont('times.php', '', 'times.php');
$pdf->SetFont('times.php', '', 16);
$pdf->Cell(0, 10, iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1251', 'Код: ') . $code, 0, 1, 'C');

// Генериране на таблицата с данни
$pdf->Cell(0, 10, iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1251', 'Код: ') . $code, 0, 1, 'C');
$pdf->Cell(0, 10, iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1251', 'Сума: ') . $amount, 0, 1, 'C');
$pdf->Cell(0, 10, iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1251', 'Крайна дата: ') . $expiryDate, 0, 1, 'C');

// Име на PDF файла
$pdfFileName = 'vaucher.pdf';

// Проверка за съхранение на PDF файла с грешка
if ($pdf->Output($pdfFileName, 'F')) {
    echo "Грешка при съхранението на PDF файла.";
} else {
    echo '<a href="' . $pdfFileName . '">Изтегли PDF файла</a>';
}

} else {
echo "Грешка при създаването на ваучъра: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Generated code is fine all works good, but I cannot make encoding to create pdf file correctly with right enconding.

Result is : Ð’Ð°ÑƒÑ‡ÐμÑ€
ÐšÐ¾Ð´: XW3CLZ81YI
Ð¡ÑƒÐ¼Ð°: 50
ÐšÑ€Ð°Ð¹Ð½Ð° Ð´Ð°Ñ‚Ð°: 2024-09-24

Comment: The standard fonts don't support Cyrillic.